# How do I determine whether Tranformation on matrix is one-to-one or onto?

Tags: matrices

[image]

How do I determine whether T is one-to-one or onto?

So I put the stuff in an augmented matrix and solved to its reduced echelon form:

[image]

Though I'm confused how I can tell if the transformation is one-to-one or onto.

Comment: Simply determine the rank of the matrix. Anyway, as domain and codomain have the same dimension,  one-to-one is equivalent to onto.

Comment: @Bernard what's "rank" "domain" and "codomain" in this matrix? how do I find those

Comment: The domain and codomain are those of the linear map $T$. The rank of a matrix is the number of  rows (or of columns) linearly independent. It is also the dimension of $\operatorname{Im}T$.

Comment: @Bernard thank you. now I need to know what I needa work on. I didn't understand anything there lol

Comment: Note the rank of a matrix can also be calculated as the size of the largest nonzero subdeterminant.

Comment: First, the matrix in your question is $2\times 3$, so it corresponds to a linear map $\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$, but $T$ is from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Second: I would suggest that you try to solve (a) without involving any matrices: just write down and solve the system of equations resulting from the equation $T(x) = 0$. You can also try to solve (b) and (c) in this way, and see if you can find any connections to what you know about matrices.